# Is there a way to decrease space utilization and potentially improve time performance for string manipulation in my C++ code?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a string manipulation code in C++ for my assignment, where I have to find a substring within a string and essentially replace it with a newly computed sequence based on other inputs (here, the string vector 'patterns'). I have been trying to find a better way to manipulate the string in order to increase efficiency (reduce space cost and possibly also reduce time complexity further). This is a sample of what I've done so far(Sorry if the strings look a bit weird, this was the best simple example I could come up with at the moment):

```
// some input variables
std::string& originalString ("__  BB  ++  AA  __  AA  __  CC  __  DD");
std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> patternMap = {
                                       {"AA", {"aaa","AAA"}}, 
                                       {"BB", {"bbb","BBB"}},
                                   };

std::size_t location = 0;
while ((location = originalString.find("__", location)) != std::string::npos) {
     const std::string subString = originalString.substr(location+4, location+6);
     std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>::iterator patternsIterator = patternMap.find(subString);
    if (patternsIterator != patternMap.end()) {
          const std::vector<std::string> patterns = patternsIterator -> second;
          std::string alternateSubString("*");
          for (const std::string& item : patterns) {
            alternateSubString.append(item + "__" );
          }
          alternateSubString.replace(alternateSubString.size() - 5, 5,"*");
          originalString.replace(location+4, 2, alternateSubString);
          location += alternateSubString.size();
      }
    ++location;
  }// Expected  value of the original string should change to: "__  *bbb__BBB*  ++  AA  __  *aaa__AAA*  __  CC  __  DD"
```

'''

Any tips regarding a better way, maybe do away with the variable alternateSubString? Trying to achieve some space/time optimization here.

Comment: Sounds like a better fit for codereview exchange, then here?

Comment: I don't understand what the expected output is supposed to be?  In your example, you replace the first instance of `BB` with `*bbb__BBB*`, but you don't attempt to change the first occurrence of `AA`, only the second occurrence.  Why is that?

Comment: use `std::unordered_map` instead of `std::ordered_map`. The former is faster than the latter. The latter preserves logical ordering of keys (in this case, alphabetical strings) when enumerating - something you don't appear to need.

Comment: If you know the operations and wanted to maximally save space, you would have to roll your own string class, which does not use continuous memory. E.g. you could say 5 chars from this memory, then 2 chars from that. This slows down access, sometimes (when?) you consolidate and move the parts together. You would have to store pointers or at least offsets (which can be smaller than full pointers). It gets complicated very soon and exceeds the effort no normally put into homework assignments. But there is a lot of potential for optimizing left.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm seems to be:

- Scan the string until the next occurrence of `__` is found.
- When found, the next word (e.g. `"BB"`) is replaced by building a new string using the vector of words in `patternMap`
- This vector of words involves concatenating each word found in `patternMap` with `__` and the entire replacement string that is built gets prefixed and postfixed with `*`. (e.g. `{"bbb","BBB"}` => `"*bbb__BBB*"` )

**Feedback**

Your implementation has a couple of instances of "backtracking" using the `replace` method to cover up a mistake made during the initial substitution loop.

It also has a few hardcoded length values that assumes spacing will be consistent between tokens.  All of this makes it slightly hard to read.

`unordered_map` will be faster than `map`. Since you don't need enumeration order, you can use unordered_map. This is a micro-optimization if the size of your map is really small.

I propose reading the initial string into tokens and keeping track if the next token needs to be replaced with the words in the patternMap.

Consider this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef unordered_map<string, vector<string>> PatternMap;


// getNext returns a pair of strings:
// The leading whitespace preceeding a word and the word itself
pair<string, string> getNext(const string& s, size_t& location);

// makeMagicWord converts a vector of words 
// into the associated magic replacement pattern
// e.g. {"AA", "BB", CC"} => "*AA__BB__CC*"
string makeMagicWord(const vector<string>& vec);

string ApplyPatterns(const std::string& original, const PatternMap& patterns)
{
    string newString;
    size_t location = 0;
    bool replacing = false;

    while (true) {
        auto p = getNext(original, location);
        string whitespace = p.first;
        string token = p.second;

        newString += whitespace;

        if (token.empty()) {
            break;
        }

        if (replacing) {
            auto itor = patterns.find(token);
            if (itor != patterns.end()) {
                token = makeMagicWord(itor->second); // itor->second = patterns[token]
            }
            replacing = false;
        }
        else if (token == "__") {
            replacing = true;
        }
        newString += token;
    }
    return newString;
}
```

The above code reads the whitespace/word tokens with a helper function, applies substitution as needed, and uses another helper function for making the replacement word.  The implementation of those two helper functions is below:

Then the implementation of our two helpers is below:

```
pair<string, string> getNext(const string& s, size_t& location) {
    string whitespace, token;

    // consume leading whitespace
    while (location < s.size() && ::isspace(s[location])) {
        whitespace += s[location];
        location++;
    }

    // consume the next token
    while (location < s.size() && !::isspace(s[location])) {
        token += s[location];
        location++;
    }

    return { whitespace, token };
}

string makeMagicWord(const vector<string>& vec) {
    std::string s = "*";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        s += ((i > 0) ? "__" : "");
        s += vec[i];
    }
    s += "*";
    return s;
}
```

Let's test it all out:

```
int main() {
    string originalString("__  BB  ++  AA  __  AA  __  CC  __  DD");
    unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> patternMap = {
                                           {"AA", {"aaa","AAA"}},
                                           {"BB", {"bbb","BBB"}}};

    string replacement = ApplyPatterns(originalString, patternMap);
    cout << originalString << endl;
    cout << replacement << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And when run, the above prints out:

```
__  BB  ++  AA  __  AA  __  CC  __  DD
__  *bbb__BBB*  ++  AA  __  *aaa__AAA*  __  CC  __  DD
```